# Convert .csv file to Json data completely and do filter in JSON data

Tags: c#, json

```
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++) {
  var objResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  for (int j = 0; j < props.Length; j++) {
    objResult.Add(props[j], csv[i][j]);
    listObjResult.Add(objResult);
  }

  string FINALJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listObjResult);
}
```

I did a conversion from csv to json. The output of json data is in FINALJSON. Now from FINALJSON I have to get only the required fields.

---

This is my data:

`[{"Ccsv":"S124","Profit":"1240025","Cost_Center_Code":"124002503","Description":"test","Status":"","Responsible_Person_Owner":"20041882"},{"Ccsv":"S136","Profit":"1360007","Cost_Center_Code":"136000799","Description":"Default Payroll","Status":"","Responsible_Person_Owner":"SSC"},{"Ccsv":"S800","Profit":"8000001","Cost_Center_Code":"800000201","Description":"SercoCaledonianSl2","Status":"","Responsible_Person_Owner":"20120730"},{"Ccsv":"s802","Profit":"8000002","Cost_Center_Code":"8.00E+58","Description":"sdfergfertxzfcx","Status":"","Responsible_Person_Owner":"3641212"}\]`

I need to get only csv and profit columns.

Comment: If you only need ccsv and profit, why are you not filtering this before you serialize to JSON? It seems like a lot of wasted effort.

Comment: Thank you. But if need other columns in future i cant get right. so first i need to convert whole to json and filter . Hoping to help me out

Comment: i converted .csv to json data. but i want to know how to filter the json data present in FINALJSON and get output of only two columns

Comment: So are you saving the JSON that was converted from the CSV somewhere, and then filtering that to produce a second JSON document with only two properties?

Comment: Yes. i am storing that result in FINALJSON.  Now i need to filter FINALJSON data and get required properties in the second result

Comment: @Tej, Try my answer so you can't get error anymore that you faced now and let me know :)

Comment: @er-sho sure i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your JSON is an array of object and you want to retrieve only two fields form it so you can try below code,

```
string json = FINALJSON;

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

var result = jArray.Select(x => new { Ccsv = x["Ccsv"], Profit = x["Profit"] }).ToList();

JArray outputJArray = JArray.FromObject(result);

//---------------Print result to console---------------

Console.WriteLine(outputJArray.ToString());
```

**Note:** You need to add newtonsoft.json nuget package from package manager console and then import `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you. i will try it.  But thing is,  the final result also be in the JSON KEY VALUE pair format.

Comment: @Tej, view **Edit 1** section in answer.

Comment: Sure i will try and let you know as soon as possible

Comment: @Tej, I updated my answer to be more specific to your need. with removed other unrelated code. :)

Comment: Another thing i am using web application ,final data should be stored in a file rather than displaying on console.

Comment: Where this json comes from because posted json in question does not matched with your above commented json.

Comment: Try this for new json => `var result = jArray.Select(x => new { Ccsv = x["Company_Code"], Profit = x["Profit_center"] }).ToList();`

Comment: To save output json to file on serve => `File.WriteAllText("Output file path on server", outputJArray.ToString());`

Comment: the final code, you had given is working fine. Thank you so much #Champion

Comment: Please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green

Comment: the commented code is coming during  .csv to json conversion and it is before serialization. anyway the before is working fine . i will ping if any.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will work for you.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var ccsv=obj.SelectToken("Ccsv");
var profit=obj.SelectToken("Profit");
```

Comment: Thank You So Much . I will try and let you know

Comment: Error reading Jobject from jsonreader . current jsonreader item is not an object : start array" ,line1,position 1..................... i got this error. what i have to do now